# Error Uncaught en Ionic 3 y Angular 4

Tags: angularjs, ionic3

Estoy preparando un proyecto con ionic y angular y siguiendo un ejemplo de unos tutoriales me da el siguiente error

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for >RegistrousuariosPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
>   Error: No component factory found for RegistrousuariosPage. Did you add it >to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Estoy haciendo el ejemplo tal cual aparece en el tutorial

P/D esta es la información del entorno de desarrollo que tengo montado

> Ionic Framework: 3.7.1
>   Ionic App Scripts: 3.0.0
>   Angular Core: 4.4.3
>   Angular Compiler CLI: 4.4.3
>   Node: 6.11.3
>   OS Platform: Windows 10
>   Navigator Platform: Win32
>   User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que intentó ejecutar y me manda ese error 
De antemano muchas gracias por responder

Comment: ¿cuál es el código del tutorial? Edita la pregunta y agrega el código como texto.

Comment: Hola Maikel, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y [answer] en el centro de ayuda, donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar tus publicaciones. Por ejemplo: en la pregunta sería ideal que añadieras el código como texto en lugar de como imagen; y en la respuesta sería bueno que añadieras una mayor descripción de cómo lo solucionaste (¿dónde añadiste la ruta en el app.ts?¿por qué no tener la ruta añadida fallaba o por qué añadirla soluciona el problema?)